# How do I convert this regular expression to RE2 for Google Sheets

Tags: regex

I have a perfectly working Regular Expression that I am trying to make work in Google Sheets.

Google Sheets requires RE2 expressions and I don't know how to format this properly.

I've read lots of questions here on StackOverflow already but unfortunately haven't had any luck.

Here is the code I already have which works perfectly.

```
(?:^|\G)(\b\w+\b),?(?=.*\1)
```

The code simply does not run in Google Sheets.

Note that the job of the code is to find words the exist in a cell multiple times.

Comment: It likely does not support `\G`. What are you trying to match?

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't understand what your regex is intended to do, and I'm especially unclear on why you're using `\G`. Can you show some text it should match on, to give us a chance to help you? In any case according to https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax, backreference (`\1`) is not supported in RE2, so that's probably also a problem.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper and Joanis  thanks for the replies. I am trying to find words that exist in a single cell multiple times. E.g. _This would would match_ and _This wouldn't_